# Post Live Data To Excel

Tags: c#, c++, excel

I have been asked to create a programme in either `C++` or `C#`, my choice, that will use `FIX messaging` to receive `Bid/Offer` prices for a variety of `FX instruments` and store the data in a database. This part I know how to do but the client has now told me he wants the ability to open n number of excel workbooks across multiple PCs to view the historic data as well as view live data as its coming in.

I have seen in excel 2010 that you can connect direct to a sql server to retrive data but the refresh fequency can only get as low as every minute. I've thought about creating an RSS feed but again that may be too slow. These guys aren't too worried about latency but they I think if theres more than a second delay they may not be too happy.

is what I'm looking to achieve even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might write a VB Macro to accomplish this, such as follows:

```
Sub Refresh_every_second()
'
' Refresh_every_second Macro
'

'
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Refresh_every_second"


End Sub
```

This macro refreshes the datasource, then calls itself recursively every second.

Note:

- To Refresh all pages, use `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`
- You may wish to introduce a means of stopping this macro, such as a click or keypress.

Edit: To refresh a specific data connection, you may use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Data Connection Name").Refresh
```

Comment: Great I will give it a try. Thanks Joe. Do you think that refreshing this everysecond will create operational issues on the persons pc?

Comment: Functionality-wise, everything is operational; that is, the user interface thread is not being blocked. As far as performance, that likely depends on the number and size of your dataset(s). For example, on my system, refreshing a 16x16 dataset via the Internet utilizes around 3% of system CPU.